# Running 32-bit libraries and binaries on Python on OS X

Tags: python, python-sphinx, visa

I have a module based on PyVisa that can only run in 32-bits mode. Since Sphinx has to be able to load the module to take the docstrings, this module (and others that inherit from PyVisa) fail.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

OS X provides "universal binaries". The same OS X native `python` command can run in 32-bit and 64-bit mode. To run Python and other software in 32-bit mode you can use `arch` command.

```
  arch -i386 pip install mypackage
  arch -i386 python run mysoftware
```

[Remember to use virtualenv when installing packages, so that you do not end up with mixed 32-bit and 64-bit packages](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/).

[Here is the actual example for Skype4Py OS X library running in 32-bit mode](https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py#skype4py-on-for-osx-64-bit-all-new-osx-versions).

Note: this has not been tested on the latest [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) version though I have not heard they would have changed universal binaries.

Answer (score 0):

The new PyVISA documentation provides two different ways to run it with 32 bit Python. Take a look here: http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#error-no-matching-architecture